# Implement and handler Android notifications via Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm working on an app that needs to receive notifications, and open a precise activity when the notification it's clicked. I implemented the Firebase service and my app receive and handler notifications, via Firebase console, when the app is foreground.

Now, I need to implement a solutions for background/killed app.
I read that I can use FCM api for send the notifications, but I don't know how to implement it and how to handler it on the app.
I'm a beginner in the notifications of Android. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you gone through the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) yet? Was there something confusing there?

Comment: I solved my problem with the docs, I maneged it taking the extra in the main. Previously I was wrong to write the key/value in the console.

Comment: now i need to change the notificatin icon. when a notificatin arrive, the device shows the default icon. the only way to change it is using the FCM API, namely building a notification whit the NotificationCompact after recieves the remote message?